# UITableViewCell dynamic heigh with aspect ratio

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, aspect-ratio

I have a UITableView with dynamic height cell. When I add static height constraint (with leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints), to UIView (in cell), everything works ok with these calculations:

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.setNeedsLayout()
var size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

The problem is when I want to add aspect-ratio to cell content - I want it to have same height as width. But it always fails with

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174291e40 UIView:0x174199f30.width == UIView:0x174199f30.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174291e90 H:[UIView:0x174199f30]-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x174199e60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174291ee0 V:[UIView:0x174199f30]-(19)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x174199e60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174291f30 H:|-(10)-[UIView:0x174199f30]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x174199e60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174291f80 V:|-(15)-[UIView:0x174199f30]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x174199e60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17029af40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x174199e60(600)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17029af90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x174199e60(34)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174291e40 UIView:0x174199f30.width == UIView:0x174199f30.height>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm thinking about submitting a TSR on this one since it looks like an apple bug.